# Как найти количество чётных и нечётных элементов в массиве NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Дан массив

```
a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, (6, 8))
```

Нужно найти количество четных и нечетных элементов в массиве.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Если Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, отметьте его как решение (слева от ответа есть галочка). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нечетные:

```
In [4]: (a % 2 != 0).sum()
Out[4]: 32
```

четные:

```
In [5]: (a % 2 == 0).sum()
Out[5]: 16
```